# Do I need to run backups with rsync as root user?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, backup

I'm creating a backup strategy for my laptop (Ubuntu) based on `rsync`. When backing-up `/etc`, I get a lot of `Operation not permitted (1)` and `Permission denied (13)` errors.

Is it required to do `sudo rsync ...` or are the problematic files and folders not needed anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you should run backups as whatever user is necessary to access all the files being backed up. In `/etc`'s case, that means `root` (so using `sudo`, or a `root`-owned cronjob or systemd timer).

Answer (score 0):

If you back-up a directory bellow things  keep in mind

```
  1. all directory and subdirectory have read and write privileges
  2. If any file that file have read privileges
```

Now if backup by any privileged user use sudo . Before using sudo check the user in /etc/sudoers file that the user have sudo access or not. If not then try as root user.